# Merge tag [android-parsequeryadapter] into [parse-android-sdk]

Tags: discussion, tags

Merge tag [android-parsequeryadapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-parsequeryadapter) into tag [parse-android-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parse-android-sdk) for the following reasons:

- Parse Query Adapter has been [deprecated](https://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#parsequeryadapter-deprecated-004) years ago and was part of the Parse Android SDK, for which there is an existing tag [parse-android-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parse-android-sdk).
- Tag is still sometimes used by mistake because users see the terms “parse”, “android” and “query”, without being aware that this was a specific feature of the Parse Android SDK (the most recent questions have since been manually retagged by me, so they won't show up currently in the tagged questions list)

This tag request is part of the Parse Community's effort to maintain Parse Platform related tags on Stack Exchange, as described [here](https://community.parseplatform.org/t/parse-related-stackexchange-tags/739).